# nodetool failed, check server logs - error during repair

Tags: cassandra

I am using Cassandra v2.1.13. Cluster with 21 nodes and 3 DC's. This is our new cluster, migrated data using sstableloader which in online now. No repairs are done before. When I run nodetetool repair for the first time after it was online, on seed nodes, I get this error

```
[2019-01-04 06:36:31,897] Repair command #21 finished

error: nodetool failed, check server logs

-- StackTrace --

java.lang.RuntimeException: nodetool failed, check server logs
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.NodeTool$NodeToolCmd.run(NodeTool.java:294)
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.NodeTool.main(NodeTool.java:206)
```

Above error says nodetool failed but the repair command was finished. I checked logs, there are no WARN/ERROR messages. I performed repair on 3 seed nodes on 3 DC's. got the same error. Repaired one node at a time.

What does this error mean exactly? Is this because nodetool lost connection after repair? Is repair completed successfully on these 3 nodes? Is it safe to continue repair on other nodes in the cluster with this error message?

Can someone please help me to understand my questions and troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: I have changed the owner for symlink files. Then repair worked fine. (if anybody needs solution in future)

Comment: what symlink files?